# How do I access this database files? (*.H##, *.I##, *.M## ...)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, vb6, dbase

I got software from a developer who move and can't be located, I just got the files but not the source code.

The thing is my client won't be using this software again but he wants to be able to access his data files from another application (the one I'm offering him).

I'm really lost, I've never seen any database (not sure if this is a database) with this kind of files.

Can some one point me in the right direction?

This are the files:

[image: list of the files they backup]

This are some of the files they copy as their database for backup.

So I'm almost sure this is the database, if I open them with a text editor, I can see some data but not in a secuencial way.

I feel kind of dumb asking, I already tried to look for *.H## *.P## *.B## extensions in Google with out any luck.

Hope some one can point me in the right direction.

Edit: I found connection in control panel, does this help any one?

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @YanetPedraza I think... and I'm not sure, the software was made in Visual Basic 5 o 6. does that help?

Comment: No, the question is what DB the other software used.  It cant be MySQL ***and*** Oracle, and those do not look like MySQL files which use typically extensions like `myi`, `myd` and `frm` for the default Inno engine

Comment: @Plutonix correct, I work with MySQL, and I already look for MySQL services, I don't have information about the database engine it was used, I have access to a computer where the software still running. What should I look for?

Comment: I had a project like this many years ago - you have a long and tedious job ahead.  You can poke thru the EXE to see if you can detect the data access engine. Failing that use a process monitor to see what modules/DLLs etc the app loads.  Then you need to reverse engineer the actual DB schema which will entail decoding all the "shortcuts" the original programmer took.

Comment: Ok, I already try looking through the software to see any connection panel / Settings ... There's nothing. I will try process monitor way and come back with results, hopefully an answer.

Comment: It's possible the files are Pervasive's Btrieve.  Btrieve is a file-level DB with no restriction or even suggestion (other than .dat) for naming files.  Look for file.ddf.  If you can find that file, it's almost definitely a Btrieve set of files, that would be one of three or five data definition files, but they are ALSO in Btrieve format.  Something like Crystal Reports would be able to access the File.ddf, however, which would allow you to see the file/field layouts and even export them.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @BillHileman no ddf file anywhere... thanks anyway.

Comment: So does your client have the software which reads these files?

Answer (score 0):

https://fileinfo.com/extension/h16

According to this it is H&R block desktop application which produces these file extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that article and is not the case, this is a custom software made in Argentina.